# Group values and put grouping name to column name

Tags: sql

There is a problem. I have this:

```
Code | Number
-------------
a    |1
a    |2
a    |3
b    |3
b    |4
```

I need to make it looks like:

```
a  |  b
---------
1  | 3
2  | 4
3  | null
```

Now I have this solution:

```
SELECT CASE Code WHEN 'a' THEN Number END AS a,
    CASE Code WHEN 'b' THEN Number END AS b
FROM tableCN
```

But it gives me this:

```
a    |  b
---------
1    | null
2    | null
3    | null
null | 3
null | 4
```

Of course i have much more Codes ans Numbers in real table.

If anyone have any advices?
I appreciate any help!

 Thank you for your time.

#### Update 1:

Great! Never have seen `PIVOT` function before. But you've hardcoded Codes:

```
( MAX(Number) FOR Code IN ([a],[b]))
```

.

I try to:

```
( MAX(Number) FOR Code IN (
SELECT  Code
  FROM testTable
  group by Code
))
```

I think I don't understand what happening at all =(

Comment: You will need to do dynamic query in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use PIVOT, but because of you do not have unique key in the table, you will need to generate one to be able to output your record set with ROW_NUMBER():

This example will do it dynamically, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c592/20:

```
  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

  DECLARE @Pivot NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SELECT @Pivot = (SELECT 
                     DISTINCT '['+CODE +'],'
                  FROM
                    tblTest
                  FOR XML PATH(''))



  SET @SQL = '
              SELECT 
                pvt.a, pvt.b
              FROM
                (SELECT Code, Number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY code ORDER BY Number) rn FROM tblTest)
                 tblTest
              PIVOT
                ( MAX(Number) FOR Code IN ('+LEFT(@Pivot,LEN(@Pivot)-1)+'))
                PVT
              '

  EXEC sp_Executesql @statement = @SQL
```

This code will do it, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c592/11:

```
 SELECT 
     rn,pvt.*
 FROM
    (
      SELECT Code, Number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY code ORDER BY Number) rn 
      FROM tblTest
     )
   tblTest
PIVOT
  ( MAX(Number) FOR Code IN ([a],[b]))
PVT
```

This is code to match your exact output, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c592/14:

```
  SELECT 
    pvt.a, pvt.b
  FROM
    (   
       SELECT Code, Number, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY code ORDER BY Number) rn 
       FROM tblTest
    )
     tblTest
  PIVOT
    ( MAX(Number) FOR Code IN ([a],[b]))
    PVT
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for rapid answers=)